# Hlint integration with (Win)GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci, hlint

Using Hlint via the command prompt works for me, but I have problem trying to perform the GHCi integration.

http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm says that "the script is at hlint.ghci [link], and a copy is installed locally in the data directory. To use, add the contents to your GHCi startup file.".

C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\cabal\hlint-1.8.23 contains this hlint.ghci file.

Now I want to find the GHCi startup file. I am using Windows 7 and according to http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html the ghci.conf file should be in a folder like .../appdata/ghc. But my ghc folder (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\ghc) only contains a ghci_history file.

So I copied the hlint.ghci file to my ghc folder and renamed it to ghci.conf.
Starting now WinGHCi it crashes, if I start GHCi it says:

> interactive>:10:91:
>      lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'
>
> interactive>:4:105:
>      lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'

What am I doing wrong?
Has the problem something to do with the missing GHCi startup file?

Comment: The `ghci.conf`(or `.ghci` on *nix) isn't present out of the box, you have to create one yourself if you want one. So it's not that. Encoding problem? Line ending issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was a bug with the `hlint.ghci` file shipped with HLint version 1.8.23 and below. HLint 1.8.24 is now available which fixes the problem, or use the online copy of `hlint.ghci` with an older version of HLint.

This bug was tracked by http://code.google.com/p/ndmitchell/issues/detail?id=531 and I originally said I "will probably fix it later today".

Comment: haskell community is one of the greatest `->will probably fix it later today` +1 (because i cannot +2)